# Avoid duplicated external links

Tags: nodes, navigation

I would like to add a section on my website (*Drupal 7*) which consists of *articles* with *external links* (as source). To avoid spam and duplicated content, I would like to avoid that users may add a URL more than one time. Basically, I need something which checks if the external URL is unique and not being used more than once.

I've looked for modules on Drupal.org, and tried googling some information. But I couldn't really find a solution. The [Link checker](http://drupal.org/project/linkchecker) module seems fine for checking if the URL is still available, but it doesn't avoid the same URL is used more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Unique Field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module:

> This module performs additional validation when a node is created or
>   updated by a user to require that a node's title, author, language,
>   and CCK fields are unique within a given context.

Comment: Considering the module has a setting for the scope of the unique values (e.g. content type, all nodes, the single node), this is the module I would suggest too.

Comment: Bit of a shame that I didn't looked into that direction. Anyway I did some testing seems to do the job so far, thanks for your help!